# Webpack production build file paths are off

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I'm running this command to try & generate a production webpack build:

`rimraf ./build/* && webpack -p --progress --config webpack.production.js`

However, when I open up the `build/index.html`, it's failing to load a lot of files because the locations are off.

1. It fails to put the correct location for the `bundle.js` file. It loads it like this: `/bundle.js`. However the `bundle.js` file is actually in the same directory as the `index.html` file in the build folder so it should load it like this `./bundle.js`
   [image]
2. If I correct the `bundle.js` path, it's still putting an incorrect route for the assets:
   [image]

What's interesting is that my app currently works with the webpack dev server when I run: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config webpack.dev.js`.

Here is what my current `webpack.production.js` file looks like:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {  
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true, // This will make the server understand "/some-link" routs instead of "/#/some-link"
  },
  entry: [
    './src/scripts' // This is where Webpack will be looking for the entry index.js file
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'), // This is used to specify folder for producion bundle
    filename: 'bundle.js', // Filename for production bundle
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules', 
      'src',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ], // Folders where Webpack is going to look for files to bundle together
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'] // Extensions that Webpack is going to expect
  },
  module: {
    // Loaders allow you to preprocess files as you require() or “load” them. 
    // Loaders are kind of like “tasks” in other build tools, and provide a powerful way to handle frontend build steps.
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, // Here we're going to use JS for react components but including JSX in case this extension is preferable
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        ],
        loader: ['react-hot-loader']
      },
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",

        // Skip any files outside of your project's `src` directory
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        ],

        // Only run `.js` and `.jsx` files through Babel
        test: /\.jsx?$/,

        // Options to configure babel with
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
        }
      },
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(), // Webpack will let you know if there are any errors

    // Declare global variables
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react',
      ReactDOM: 'react-dom',
      _: 'lodash'
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
      hash: true
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    }),
  ]
}
```

And just in case, this is what my current `webpack.dev.js` file looks like:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {  
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true, // This will make the server understand "/some-link" routs instead of "/#/some-link"
  },
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/', // Specify the local server port
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // Enable hot reloading
    './src/scripts' // This is where Webpack will be looking for the entry index.js file
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'), // This is used to specify folder for producion bundle
    filename: 'bundle.js', // Filename for production bundle
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules', 
      'src',
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ], // Folders where Webpack is going to look for files to bundle together
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'] // Extensions that Webpack is going to expect
  },
  module: {
    // Loaders allow you to preprocess files as you require() or “load” them. 
    // Loaders are kind of like “tasks” in other build tools, and provide a powerful way to handle frontend build steps.
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, // Here we're going to use JS for react components but including JSX in case this extension is preferable
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        ],
        loader: ['react-hot-loader']
      },
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",

        // Skip any files outside of your project's `src` directory
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        ],

        // Only run `.js` and `.jsx` files through Babel
        test: /\.jsx?$/,

        // Options to configure babel with
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
        }
      },
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // Hot reloading
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(), // Webpack will let you know if there are any errors

    // Declare global variables
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react',
      ReactDOM: 'react-dom',
      _: 'lodash'
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
      hash: false
    })
  ]
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am facing same issue, did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

faced a similar issue. setting `output.publicPath: "/"` in webpack.dev.js and `output.publicPath: "./"` in webpack.prod.js, did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error when running `npm run watch`, local dev still worked, but after deploying to demo server the app crashed on wrong js-file url.

#### Cause:

Some changes in my webpack.mix.js started compiling a **index.html** file that was found by the browser, instead of the **app.blade** I was using.

Fixed the paths by setting: `publicPath: './public/'`
(Note that it's a relative path). Also, I removed the generated url by setting `inject: false,` in the `HtmlWebpackPlugin({` section and used the asset('/...') logic.